# Azure function - IOT Hub (EventHub) supported Extensions not working

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I've created a PowerShell Core v7 Function App and added an IOT Hub (Event Hub) Function. When I run it I get the following error:

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: One or more loaded extensions do not meet the 
minimum 
requirements. For more information see https://aka.ms/func-min-extension-versions.
ExtensionStartupType EventHubsWebJobsStartup from assembly 
'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.EventHubs, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not meet the required minimum version of 4.3.0.0. 
Update your NuGet package reference for Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs to 
4.3.0 or later.
```

Reading the error says that the following article should fix the problem - https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1987

I've added this into my hosts.json and this is when I get the error:

```
{
"version": "2.0",
"managedDependency": {
"Enabled": true
},
"extensionBundle": {
"id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
"version": "[3.3.0, 4.0.0)"
}
}
```

What am I missing here? I can't find any info anywhere other than this MS doc which says the same thing - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-register#explicitly-install-extensions

Answer (score 0):

This morning I recreated the Function App and it all just seemed to work.  Bit strange as I'd tried this already.
James